# How to access catch without an error javascript

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I may be misinformed, but I have built my `try catch` on the basis that if there is no error I will run my code inside the catch as so:

```
try {
  //Something valid
} catch (err) {
  if (!err) {
     //do something
  }
}
```

Is it possible to catch errors like `JSON.parse()` that will fail 50% of the time, but you know it will fail half the time, the other half I would like my application not to crash and be able to run as normal?

Comment: Umm weird question.  Why not, use a flag and after the try-catch check that flag and avoid this weird logic.

Answer (score 3):

You can explicitly throw something at the end of the `try` block if you want to enter the `catch` block regardless:

```js
try {
  //Something valid
  throw null;
} catch (err) {
  if (!err) {
     console.log('doing something');
  }
}
```

Or, perhaps a bit more precisely, check if the `err` is an `instanceof Error` in the `catch`:

```js
try {
  //Something valid
  throw null;
} catch (err) {
  if (!(err instanceof Error)) {
     console.log('doing something');
  }
}
```